# I have deployed my react single page site to firebase and getting this error of not found 404 after refresh at any page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, refresh, single-page-application

This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory.

You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check your firebase.json and make sure the public directory is pointing to a directory that contains an index.html file.

You can also add a 404.html in the root of your site to replace this page with a custom error page.

Comment: I found the answer : I have to add the below in firebase.json                                        "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    } ]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.